# Python 2.7.8 How to restart the game code

Tags: python

I am looking on how to restart this code without actually restarting the game. I want to be able have the game restart on its on.

```
print 'Welcome to the game of NIM: '
player=1
state=21
print 'The number of objects is now ',state
while True:
    print 'Player ',player
    while True:
        move=input('What is your move? ')
        if move in [1,2,3] and move<state:
            break
        print 'Illegal move.'
    state=state-move
    print 'The number of objects is now ',state

    if state==1:
        print 'Player ',player,' wins!'
        break
    if player==1:
        player=2
    else:
        player=1
print 'Game is over.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in a function, and call that function in a while loop:

```
from sys import exit #To exit if the user does not want to try again
print 'Welcome to the game of NIM: '
def game():
    player=1
    state=21
    print 'The number of objects is now ',state
    while True:
        print 'Player ',player
        while True:
            move=input('What is your move? ')
            if move in [1,2,3] and move<state:
                break
            print 'Illegal move.'
        state=state-move
        print 'The number of objects is now ',state

        if state==1:
            print 'Player ',player,' wins!'
            break
        if player==1:
            player=2
        else:
            player=1
    if raw_input('Would you like to try again? ').lower().startswith('y'):
        return #To exit from the function cleanly
    exit() #To exit from the program cleanly if the user does not want to try again
def run():
    while True:
        game()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: how do you exit exactly?

Comment: I just edited the code, now, the program will ask if the user wants to try again, if they do, it will restart, if not, it will exit using [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Comment: Use the link I added.